# Wrapping it (spec) block inside a block is not working in rails rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to rescue an exception in all my test cases by wrapping it in a rescue block, but getting this error.

```
  raise WrongScopeError,
        "`#{name}` is not available on an example group (e.g. a " \
        "`describe` or `context` block). It is only available from " \
        "within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from " \
        "constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. " \
        "`before`, `let`, etc)."

  `rescue_with_ex` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
```

My example below:

```
  describe 'skip rescues' do

        def rescue_with_ex
            begin
                yield
            rescue => e
                skip("Skipped")
            end
        end

        rescue_with_ex do
            it 'raise and mark true' do
              dummy = 1 > nil # Raises exception
                expect(dummy).to be_eql(true)
            end
        end
    end
```

Use Case: Trying to skip in a particular exception and have that code in common like a wrapper.

Any other alternatives for this use case will be appreciated. TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add that inside the it

```
describe 'skip rescues' do

    def rescue_with_ex
        begin
            yield
        rescue => e
            skip("Skipped")
        end
    end

    it 'raise and mark true' do
        rescue_with_ex do
          dummy = 1 > nil # Raises exception
        end

        expect(dummy).to be_eql(true)
    end
end
```